# probability of non smokers equals probability of smokers

Tags: probability

> Suppose that $10$ % students are smokers.In a random sample of $10$ students, the probability that number of nonsmokers equals the number of smokers is

What i try: If $10$% students are smokers. Then $90$ % students are non smokers.

Let $p$ be the probability of smokers and $q$ be the probability of nonsmokers.

So $$p=\frac{1}{10}$$ and $$q=\frac{9}{10}$$

I did not understand How $p=q$ which is asked in question.

Please,Help me , Thanks

Comment: Hint: It's the same question as: "What is the probability that in a sample of 10 students, there are exactly 5 smokers?"

Comment: The problem statement is not stating anything like $p=q$. Forget about that. The probabilities are not the same, the number of outcomes is the same. It's only a play on words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use binomial pmf

$$\mathbb{P}[X=5]=\binom{10}{5}(\frac{1}{10})^5(\frac{9}{10})^5$$

Answer (score 1):

Probability is not the same as sampling of an event. Consider tossing a fair coin. Now, probability for any given toss to be heads or tails is $0.5$, but it need not be the case that when I actually toss a coin 10 times that 5 of them come heads and 5 of them come tails.

This is an important distinction between the probability of an event occurring and it actually occurring.

In your case, lets try to bring it back to coin tosses. Let us say that a smoker will always flip heads, and a non-smoker will flip tails. But here, the coin is biased. On any given throw, it has got a 90% chance to be tails, and is not a fair coin.

Now, you get 10 people to toss it. It may generate any sequence of smokers (S) and non-smokers (N). For example

$$S S NSNNNSSS$$
$$SSNSSNSSNN$$
$$SNSNSNSNSN$$

are all plausible outcomes. Now, over all outcomes of 10 tosses, what is the probability that the sequence generated has number of S and N equal?